# SerializeField Indexed by Enum in ScriptableObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I have an array/list/dictionary serialised in the Unity editor's inspector in a way that the designer does not need to be aware of the enum indices under the hood.

As in;

```
public enum foobar { foo, bar }
[SerializeField] List<string> optionsForTheDesigner = new List< string>();
```

In the inspector this would be shown as (ideally with foo and bar as an enum drop down menu);

[image: Labelled from enum]

And then accessed in code as;

```
fooValueFromTheDesigner = optionsForTheDesigner[foobar.foo];
barValueFromTheDesigner = optionsForTheDesigner[foobar.bar];
```

Rather than the inspector showing;

[image: Labelled as Elements]

In case it makes a difference this in a ScriptableObject.

Edit: Changed 'editor' to 'inspector' for clarity. Changed text examples to pictures.

Edit2: I have ended up plumbing for something similar to rustyBucketBay's answer, but using the enum rather than an int. This displays in the editor like below. If needed I can then convert this into an enum indexed array/List at runtime or with a helper function prior to building.

[image: Chosen route]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a comment, only arrays and lists can be serialized, not dictionaries. Check [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html).

You can get the names of your enum type to an string array. The index of the item in the array will be the index of the enum type, so it can be accessed as you want.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public enum foobar { foo, bar }

public class GetEnumValues : MonoBehaviour
{
    string[] optionsForTheDesigner;
    void Start() {
        optionsForTheDesigner = Enum.GetNames(typeof(foobar));
    }

    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.N)) {
            Debug.Log($"foo name: { optionsForTheDesigner[(int)foobar.foo]}");
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.M)) {
            Debug.Log($"bar name: { optionsForTheDesigner[(int)foobar.bar]}");
        }
    }
}
```

Log result:

[image]

EDIT:

To do what you want to do you cannot use an `enum`. Enums are serializable, but their value is set at compile time as far as I know. Kind of what you want to achieve would be possible if dictionaries or tuples where serializable by the unity editor (not the same as the .Net serialization) but they are not. Check the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html).

To achieve what you want you need to make your editor template class yourself to be used in the inspector like this:

```
[Serializable]
class MyInspectorCoolClass {
    int myInt;
    string myString;
}

class MyMonoBehaviour: MonoBehaviour {
    public MyInspectorCoolClass myFields; //your fields will be displayed in the inspector
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66907984/how-to-access-dictionary-from-other-classs-function-in-c-unity/66908124#66908124) might be helpfull.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question from editor to inspector as I realised I was not being clear as to where I wanted the enum names. Is there a way to use these names as the array/list index for the purpose of viewing said array/list in the inspector?

Comment: This is another reason for wanting to avoid showing the index in the inspector. That said enum values can be set in code with enum foobar { foo = 0, bar = 1 }. I have ended up plumbing for something similar to your suggestion but using the enum rather than an int. I was hoping to be able to index rather than having to constantly find the appropriate record, but I guess I can always convert the list of enum value pairs to an enum indexed array on first access. I will add a screen shot to the bottom of the question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
[System.Serializable]
public class SerializableDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class OBJ
    {
        public TKey Key;
        public TValue Value;
    }

    public List<OBJ> dictionary = new List<OBJ>();
}
```

And use like:

```
    public SerializableDictionary<TileModifierType, GameObject> testList = new SerializableDictionary<TileModifierType, GameObject>();
```

Comment: You might want to also derive from IDictionary<,> and implement the interface on the SerializableDictionary class.